# Tuning postgresql.conf when benchmark

Tags: postgresql, benchmark, enterprisedb

**Description:**

We build a new database server Enterprisedb v9.3 (PostgreSQL commercial), so we use JMX to benchmark it with 1000 users. Here is our detailed information:

```
Operating System: Centos 6 x64
RAM: 8 GB
CPU: 2 CPU, Intel(R) Xeon (R) CPU @ 2.50 GHz 
User quantity: 1000
```

**Query to benchmark:**

```
select count(distinct(a.id)) 
from table_a a 
join table_b on a.id = b.fk_id  (*)

Running (*) before benchmark : 100 ms -> 200 ms
Running (*) during benchmark : 3000 ms -> 180000 ms (increase 30 -> 900 times)
CPU is used by benchmark: ~ 95 %
RAM is used by benchmark: ~ 3.5 GB
```

**postgresql.conf file:**

```
max_connections = 2000
shared_buffers = 5000MB 
temp_buffers = 32MB 
work_mem = 5MB  
maintenance_work_mem = 1MB
effective_cache_size = 1000MB
checkpoint_segments = 128
edb_enable_icache = on
enable_indexscan = on
enable_mergejoin = on
enable_nestloop = on
edb_dynatune = 90
edb_dynatune_profile = oltp
```

**Questions:**

1. If resources do not change, how we can improve our configuration? (can we edit parameters in `postgresql.conf`?)
2. Can we use **pgbench** to benchmark with query (*) above?

Comment: We use pgbouncer for pooling and performance is better.  This topic is difficult to discuss .

Comment: Q1: it's hard to say. Q2: the answer is "can" but only pgbench database.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can run those queries in pgbench. Look for the parts talking about custom scripts:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgbench.html

2. The `max_connections`, and `shared_buffers` seem really high for the server you have. 25% of RAM for shared_buffers would be more reasonable, and getting a connection pooler like pgbouncer to handle lots of connections would be much more productive.

You might find this useful as well:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Hope that helps. =)

Comment: Thanks. As I know, pgbench just benchmark on its tables (pgbench_accounts, pgbench_branches, pgbench_history, and pgbench_tellers), so how can I use pgbench for my tables ?

Comment: You can use the -f flag on pgbench, as stated in the documentation. If you want to get fancier, there are a bunch of other options you can use. But you can probably just get away with a begin/commit and that query, in a file.   



     -f filename
     --file=filename

     Read transaction script from filename. See below for details. -N, -S, and -f are mutually exclusive.